# Что значат аргументы фукнции glVertex3f в OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

```
gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
gl2.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
gl2.glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0f);
gl2.glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.25f, 0.0f);
gl2.glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
gl2.glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
gl2.glEnd();
```

Это четырехугольник на OpenGL. Я только не понимаю что означают эти числа в аргументах функции. Никто не объясняет как их понимать. Пробовал менять эти числа и получал кривые изображения. Если это координаты как их трактовать?

Comment: Это координаты на плоскости XYZ, смотри ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Функция glVertex3f() получает в качестве параметров ее X, Y и Z координаты. Первая вершина треугольника смещена только от оси Y на 1, таким образом, мы расположим ее точно в центре и она будет самой верхней. Следующая вершина будет располагаться на оси Х слева от центра и на оси Y вниз от центра. Эта вершина будет расположена внизу слева. Третья вершина будет справа и снизу от центра.

```
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  // Вверх
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);  // Слева снизу
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);  // Справа снизу
```

Ссылка: -> http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/nehe02.htm

Comment: @Djasir например?)

Comment: Например, я думал что эти числа каким то образом складываются. Допустим glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f). Я думал что они преобразуются в 010 и каким то образом обрабатываются. В общем глупо)) В общем пойду читать про основы компьютерной графики.